# Why should $\subset$ denote "subset"?

Tags: soft-question, notation

Some mathematicians use the symbol $\subset$ to denote that a set is a subset of another set, i. e., $$A\subset B\quad:\iff\quad\text{Every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$}.$$
Thus, using this definition, $A\subset A$ for all set $A$. I find this distasteful, since $m<n$ in arithmetic means that $m$ is strictly less than $n$. If find it more intuitive to use $\subset$ for "proper subset", and $\subseteq$ for "subset".

> Why do some mathematician define $A\subset B$ to mean that $A$ is a subset (not necessarily proper subset) of $B$?

Comment: It's just a notation, personally I prefer $\subsetneq$ to denote proper subsets and use $\subseteq$ when it does not really matter.

Comment: As with many things about notation, the answer is probably historical. Specifically, it was hard to typset stuff, and $\subseteq$ was the more commonly-needed symbol, so they used that.

Comment: If their proof doesn't require use of a set being a proper subset, just some subset, then $\subset$ is faster to write than $\supseteq$

Comment: Laziness. One also uses non-strict inclusion much more frequently.

Comment: It would have been more consistent with $<$ to write $\subset$ for proper inclusion, but I guess it's probably too late to change an established convention now.

Comment: Indeed, when Schröder introduced the $\subset$ notation, he explicitly pointed out the analogy to $<$. And that analogy is so powerful that for me as an order theorist, using $\subset$ to mean $\subseteq$ (so its own reflexive closure) is horrifying. When I use $\subset$, it **is** as the reflexive reduction, though because the horror has become a convention, I am compelled to flag the (sensible but) nonstandard usage.

Answer (score 4):

Not speaking for other mathematicians, but in general, the notation is not as important as being explicit about what one means. Therefore, it is less helpful to say $A \subset B$ or $A \subseteq B$ than it is to say "Let $A$ be a proper subset of $B$," or what have you.

Comment: I actually find that quite jarring. I read: "Let $A$ be a subset of $B$ be a proper subset of $B$." If you're going to spell out the notation, then I think it makes more sense to dispense with the symbols entire: "Let $A$ be a proper subset of $B$."

Comment: Good point. Hence the ``what have you.''

Answer (score 2):

Notation are used for our convenience, Some mathematician may use $\subseteq$ for subset while other use $\subset$.
I prefer to use $\subseteq$ for  subset and $\subset$ for proper subset.we may use any notation for our convenience,but you need to define it earlier.